# How to let external script modify present vim buffer

Tags: vim, buffer

Let say I'm editing `somefile.txt` in Vim. Is there a way to run an external script saved in a file `some_perl_script.pl` and let the script modify the presently open buffer in place?

Sorry, I've searched, but the keywords I've used give too broad responses. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `some_perl_script.pl` takes text from standard input and returns text to standard output, Vim allows you to use it as a "filter":

```
:%!some_perl_script.pl
```

See `:help filter`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new both to Vim and Perl. In order to do as you say, does `some_perl_script.pl` need special setup in order to accept input from Vim buffer and write it back out to Vim buffer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that some_perl_script.pl takes input on stdin and produces output on stdout.

You can use the [formatprg](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatprg%27) option with [`gq`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq). When you type `gq` the selected lines will be formated with the program set with formatprg.

So you can put the following in your vimrc (assuming thats how you run some_perl_script.pl)

```
set formatprg=some_perl_script.pl
```

Then in the buffer run `gggqG` to format the whole buffer.

Take a look at `:h formatprg` and `:h gq`